# Is everything an object in ruby?

Tags: ruby, object

Is everything in ruby an object? Does this include `Fixnum`s?

Comment: I don't think methods in ruby can be treated like objects.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by "everything". `Fixnum`s are, as the others have demonstrated. Classes also are, as instances of class `Class`. Methods, operators and blocks aren't, but can be wrapped by objects (`Proc`). Simple assignment is not, and can't. Statements like `while` also aren't and can't. Comments obviously also fall in the latter group.

Most things that actually *matter*, i.e. that you would wish to manipulate, are objects (or can be wrapped in objects).

Comment: +1 Love these counter-examples. Saying that everything is an object without considering EVERYTHING is slightly brainwashed :)

Comment: +1 - Superb that's what i was trying to say in some other question, from which this question has been spawned.

Comment: Why isn't `while` an object?

Comment: @Ziggy: I am not sure what you're asking, but... why would it be?

Comment: Yeah, I mean to say "I wonder why they didn't try to make while an object that takes a block". I mean, I know that could lead to some janky magic, but at the same time if you set out to write a language where "everything's an object" why not go all the way. Why not let `=>` be a method. Why not find a way to make argument lists an object. Why not! I guess it's because you would end up with a crazy eso-lang, rather than an industry standard.

Comment: Just learnt this and wondering, Objects are cloneable, but fixnum being an object is not clonable.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. `Fixnum` is a class, which inherits from `Integer`, which inherits from `Numeric`, which finally inherits from `Object`.

Or, why don't you just ask it? :)

```
1.is_a? Object # => true
1.class # => Fixnum
Fixnum.is_a? Object # => true
```

Reading the [Ruby info](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/about/) and [documentation](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/) on the website is a good idea too.

Comment: Note- From rails 2.4.0 Fixnum and Bignum added into Integer Class.
Now-
1.is_a? Object # => true
1.class # => Integer  (not Fixnum).

Answer (score 5):

Practically everything in Ruby is an Object, with the exception of control structures. Whether or not under the covers a method, code block or operator is or isn't an Object, they are represented as Objects and can be thought of as such.

Take a code block for example:

```
def what_is(&block)
  puts block.class
  puts block.is_a? Object
end

> what_is {}
Proc
true
=> nil
```

Or for a Method:

```
class A
  def i_am_method
    "Call me sometime..."
  end
end

> m = A.new.method(:i_am_method)
> m.class
Method
> m.is_a? Object
true
> m.call
"Call me sometime..."
```

And operators (like +, -, [], <<) are implemented as methods:

```
class String
  def +
    "I'm just a method!"
  end
end
```

For people coming into programming for the first time, what this means in a practical sense is that all the rules that you can apply to one kind of Object can be extended to others. You can think of a String, Array, Class, File or any Class that you define as behaving in much the same way. This is one of the reasons why Ruby is easier to pick up and work with than some other languages.

Comment: `&` unary operator converts the block into a `Proc`. But the block itself is not an object: `{|n| n+1}.class
# => 
SyntaxError: (irb):4: syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting '}'`

Answer (score 2):

[Yes everything is an object in ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/about/), and that includes [Fixnum](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Fixnum.html)

Answer (score 2):

Ruby doen't have any primitives (like int, char etc in java), so every value (anything that can sit on the right of an assignment statement) is an object. However, control statements, methods, and other features of the language syntax aren't.

Answer (score 1):

Yup.

```
> Fixnum.is_a?(Object)   #=> true
```

To see the chain of inheritance:

```
> pp Fixnum.ancestors
[Fixnum,
 Integer,
 Precision,
 Numeric,
 Comparable,
 Object,
  ...
 Kernel]
 => nil
```

Comment: `#ancestors` gives all the included modules as well, not just the inheritance chain.

Comment: Also, `pp` isn't available by default, at least in 1.8.7p174.

Comment: Fixnum.is_a? Object  
(irb):9: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
=> true
Because Fixnum and Bignum added into Integer Class.