# Conditional statements are objects in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, object

In [Ruby Language - About](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/about/) we can find this sentence:

"*In Ruby, everything is an object. Every bit of information and code can be given their own properties and actions*"

It is being pretty difficult to understand where the limits are.  We can't say conditional statements are objects, can we? If not, what "every bit of information" means here?

Comment: Keywords aren't objects.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429553/is-everything-an-object-in-ruby

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That statement is a bit of an exaggeration.  Every **data item** in Ruby is an *Object* (or descendant of Object, more precisely) and [`Proc`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Proc.html) is one example of a bit of code which is also an object.  But there are many concepts in Ruby which are not Objects, e.g. keywords, arbitrary statements, etc.

However, complete statements always *evaluate* into an object.  I think the author's intent was to dramatically describe that there are no values, primitive or otherwise, which are not also Objects in the language.

```ruby
# Data items are all objects.
1.class # => Fixnum
(2 ** 64).class # => Bignum
"a".class # => String
{}.class # => Hash
nil.class # => NilClass
lambda {|x| x}.class # => Proc

# Statements, including conditionals, *evaluate* to objects.
(true ? "a" : 1).class # => String
(false ? "a" : 1).class # => Fixnum
(if true; 'a'; else; 1; end).class # => String
(if false; 'a'; else; 1; end).class # => Fixnum
(while true; break; end).class # => NilClass
```

Comment: One could abstract a conditional statement as a `lambda { |c, t, f| c ? t.call : f.call } `, which makes it an object as such (without an immediate valuation), meaning in Ruby it's possible to build code on run-time through the use of objects.

Comment: @Romain: yes, this is absolutely true, but the `lambda` statement still just returns a `Proc` object.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborated answer! This makes sense now :-)

Comment: @maerics I agree. My interpretation of "everything in ruby is an object" is more "everything in ruby can be put in an object", which includes data and also behavior.